# How to use Typescript generics to construct a function that can be used on similar objects?

Tags: typescript, types

I have two types that share a subset of properties, e.g.

```
type A = {
  x: number
  y: number
  desc: string
}

type B = {
  x: number
  y: number
  address: number
}
```

I'd like to just have one function that can do something to these types, only reading some of the props:

```
const munge = <T>(list: T[]): T[] => list.sort((a,b) => a.x - b.x)
```

Obviously this does not work (error is `Property 'x' does not exist on type 'T'.`) even if I attempt to use `munge` on an `A[]` (thus I learn generics do not work like C++ templates).

I get that this may be a limitation of the language, but what can I even do here? Must I specifically define munge in terms of the types A and B or some other type that is a subset of them? The point here is I would like to have the return type be `T[]`, that is to say, if I send in a `B[]` to `munge`, I'd like typescript to understand that munge would in that instance return back a `B[]`. It would seem that if I define `munge` explicitly to accept A or B (or its as-yet-unwritten base type `C` having only a `x` prop), there'll be more ugliness later in casting it back to whatever type it went in to `munge` as.

For example, it would not be acceptable that I need to write two implementations of `munge`, one taking `A[]` and one taking `B[]`. Is it true that this is the only practical clean way to do it? (it's not clean)

Answer (score 2):

So far this code seems to be easy enough to read and gets the job done. I don't like it though.

```
type A = {
  x: number;
  desc: string;
};
type B = {
  x: number;
  addr: number;
};
type C = {
  x: number;
};

const munge = <T extends C>(list: T[]): T[] => list.sort((a, b) => a.x - b.x);

const aa: A[] = [
  { x: 5, desc: "a" },
  { x: 0, desc: "" },
];

console.log(aa);
const z = munge(aa);
// editor shows type of z is A[]. I'm satisfied...
console.log(z);
```

Comment: This is the answer. [Structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) might not sit too comfortably with someone coming from a more rigid type-system, but it's the natural way to express this in TS.